# Spring Data Jpa repository in spring batch tasklet throws TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm having problems using a Spring Data Jpa repository inside a Spring Batch tasklet.
I'd expect to have a valid hibernate transaction in the `MyOrderTasklet's` `execute` method using the `myTransactionManager` that is configured for this step. But as soon as `flush()` is called or if the execute method is left (without explicitly calling `flush()`). I get a

```
TransactionRequiredException"no transaction is in progress".
```

When debugging I see that a transaction gets created by spring batch before entering the tasklet's execute method and that a valid hibernateTransaction is created and put in the `org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext` instance by calling `getJpaDialect().beginTransaction()` in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#doBegin()`.

When methods of the `orderRepository` are called, I see that the call to `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager#getTransaction` finds an existing transaction and calls `handleExistingTransaction`. But later on `org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl#isTransactionInProgress` returns false because no hibernateSession can be found.

I see that different Hibernate sessions and `EntityManagers` are created for transaction around the tasklet's execute method and for the calls to the repository. The outer hibernate transaction which is bound to the outer hibernate session can't be found by the inner hibernate session.

Any ideas how to solve this? How can the same hibernate session be used for the tasklet's execute method and the calls to the repository? Can the `hibernateTemplate` maybe be propagated to other sessions somehow?

Here's some code extract to show my setup:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyRepositoryConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=MyRepositoryConfig.class)
public class MyRepositoryConfig {

    @Autowired
    private InfrastructureConfiguration infrastructureConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(infrastructureConfiguration.hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model");
        factory.setDataSource(infrastructureConfiguration.dataSource());
        if (StringUtils.hasText(infrastructureConfiguration.getSchema())) {
            factory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.default_schema", infrastructureConfiguration.getSchema());
        }
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name= { "transactionManager", "myTransactionManager"})
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyRepositoryService myRepositoryService() {
        return new myRepositoryServiceImpl();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class DefaultInfrastructureConfiguration implements InfrastructureConfiguration {

    @Value("${my.schema:MYSCHEMA}")
    private String defaultSchema;

    @Value("${novis.jdbc.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//example.com/example}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${novis.jdbc.username:scott}")
    private String jdbcUsername;

    @Value("${novis.jdbc.password:tiger}")
    private String jdbcPassword;

    @Value("${novis.jdbc.driverClassName:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver}")
    private String jdbcDriverClassName;

    @Value("${novis.hibernate.database:ORACLE}")
    private String hibernateDatabase;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        ds.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
        ds.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
        ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");

        return ds;
    }

    @Override
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.valueOf(Database.class, hibernateDatabase));
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSchema() {
        return defaultSchema;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(MyRepositoryConfig.class)
public class OrderManagerConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myTransactionManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager myTransactionManager;

    ....        
    @Bean
    public Tasklet MyOrderTasklet() {
        return new MyOrderTasklet();
    }
    ....
    @Bean
    public Step processMyOrderErrorsStep() {
        return steps.get("processMyOrderErrorsStep").
            transactionManager(myTransactionManager).
            tasklet(myOrderProcessor()).
            listener(stepExecutionLoggerListener()).
            build();
    }
    ....
}

public class MyOrderTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager myTransactionManager;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        for (Order order : orderRepository.findByErrorIsNotNullAndErrorHandledFalse()) {
            // Handle the error...
            order.setErrorHandled(true);
            orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
03 Sep 2014 09:53:39:902 ERROR AbstractStep:225 - Encountered an error executing step processMyOrderErrorsStep in job processMyOrderErrors
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:959) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.flush(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.flush(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:436) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:404) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ch.local.ordermanager.MyOrderTasklet.execute(MyOrderTasklet.java:41) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.start(SimpleJobOperator.java:314) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at ch.local.batchmanager.BatchJobRunner.runJob(BatchJobRunner.java:20) [classes/:?]
    at ch.local.batchmanager.BatchManager.run(BatchManager.java:30) [classes/:?]
    at ch.local.common.base.AbstractBatchApplication.execute(AbstractBatchApplication.java:38) [classes/:?]
    at ch.local.batchmanager.BatchManager.main(BatchManager.java:9) [classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I defined the hibernate verison in the pom.xml to be 4.3.5, another library in our project has a dependency to hibernate 3.6.10, which was then used (and I did not notice). The error disappeared after getting rid of Hibernate 3 and using the latest hibernate 4 version (4.3.5 at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the following piece of code:

```
@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Usually you don't configure an entityManager singleton, you let Spring decide when to create a new instance at transaction boundary.

The entity manager is usually being inserted using:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Even if you don't declare such bean, Spring will still create one and will provide you the one that's suitable for your current running transaction.

Using a singleton EntityManager is problematic, since the EntityManager is not thread-safe and reusing it without clearing might also lead to memory leaks and stale entity versions.

Comment: I have also seen application that simply do an @Autowire of the EntityManager. But I think that other comment from Vlad: "Even if you don't declare such bean, Spring will still create one and will provide you the one that's suitable for your current running transaction.", I am not sure about that, I think you need to declare the EntityManager explicitly in your Spring config.

Comment: Also btw I would always prefer to have definition like "hibernate.default_schema" or the package scan directory to be defined in the spring configuration XML rather then in the code. You might want to configure those parameters without recompiling the code. So yes, I think configuration should always belong into XML files rather then application code.

Comment: The EntityManager is being context related. Two concurrent threads will use a different EntityManager instance, so Spring must create such object only for the current transaction life-cycle and simply discard it when the transaction ends. If you explicitly create it how will it get along with the context-bound nature of the persistence context bean?

Comment: You might be right, but what I mean is like in this example here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/openmeetings-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/openmeetings-applicationContext.xml?view=markup there is a bean "entityManagerFactory" But yes I see the "@PersistenceContext" is the right annotation to use. so +1 to your answer Vlad.

Comment: @VladMihalcea: I don't know why I added the EntityManager bean - it's of course wrong. I removed it but still have the same issue. Since I only use spring-data-jpa I don't inject the entityManager by myself at all.
What I also  noticed is that this has nothing to do with spring batch. If I just create a TransactionTemplate with the transactionManager and use some repository calls inside its execute call, I have the same behaviour (TransactionRequiredException). This does not come as a surprise because spring batch is actually doing exactly this. Running the tasklet in a TransactionTemplate.

Comment: @seba.wagner: "... I would always prefer to have definition [...] to be defined in the spring configuration XML rather then in the code". This is a java config based project, so there's no XML config anymore.

Comment: @James Make sure you don't use auto-commit=true. I see the TransactionInterceptor in your stack trace so the spring transaction management is in place. The only thing missing is your data source configuration. And also the hibernate properties you set. Could you please provide it?

Comment: @VladMihalcea: I added the DefaultInfrastructureConfiguration class to the original question containing the DataSource config.

Comment: Looks fine. Let's see if the alias is an issue here. Try replacing "myTransactionManager" with "transactionManager".